# Riverpod Generator should be generating a stream but instead its generating an async value

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have done this exact example in a previous app line for line a the user stream.g.dart generator generated a stream I could use but this time its not generating a stream:

userStream.dart:

```
part 'userstream.g.dart';

@riverpod
class Users extends _$Users {
  @override
  Stream<User?> build() {
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();
  }
}
```

it generated this userstream.g.dart:

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'userstream.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// RiverpodGenerator
// **************************************************************************

String _$usersHash() => r'7d9a531b75593cd952a52ca555796bde5a421750';

/// See also [Users].
@ProviderFor(Users)
final usersProvider = AutoDisposeStreamNotifierProvider<Users, User?>.internal(
  Users.new,
  name: r'usersProvider',
  debugGetCreateSourceHash:
      const bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.product') ? null : _$usersHash,
  dependencies: null,
  allTransitiveDependencies: null,
);

typedef _$Users = AutoDisposeStreamNotifier<User?>;
// ignore_for_file: type=lint
// ignore_for_file: subtype_of_sealed_class, invalid_use_of_internal_member
```

so when I try to use the stream it won't work its saying:

The argument type 'AsyncValue<User?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<User?>?'

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    var users = ref.watch(usersProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      //Streams can always be put in a streamProvider
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          //if has to be nullable becasue if the user is not signed in its null
          stream: users, //
```

Last time I did this exact login line for line and the userstream.g.dart looked like this:

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'userstream.dart';

subtype_of_sealed_class, invalid_use_of_internal_member, unused_element, constant_identifier_names, unnecessary_raw_strings, library_private_types_in_public_api

/// Copied from Dart SDK
class _SystemHash {
  _SystemHash._();

  static int combine(int hash, int value) {
    // ignore: parameter_assignments
    hash = 0x1fffffff & (hash + value);
    // ignore: parameter_assignments
    hash = 0x1fffffff & (hash + ((0x0007ffff & hash) << 10));
    return hash ^ (hash >> 6);
  }

  static int finish(int hash) {
    // ignore: parameter_assignments
    hash = 0x1fffffff & (hash + ((0x03ffffff & hash) << 3));
    // ignore: parameter_assignments
    hash = hash ^ (hash >> 11);
    return 0x1fffffff & (hash + ((0x00003fff & hash) << 15));
  }
}

String _$UsersHash() => r'7d9a531b75593cd952a52ca555796bde5a421750';

/// See also [Users].
final usersProvider = AutoDisposeNotifierProvider<Users, Stream<User?>>(
  Users.new,
  name: r'usersProvider',
  debugGetCreateSourceHash:
      const bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.product') ? null : _$UsersHash,
);
typedef UsersRef = AutoDisposeNotifierProviderRef<Stream<User?>>;

abstract class _$Users extends AutoDisposeNotifier<Stream<User?>> {
  @override
  Stream<User?> build();
}
```

This this some kind of bug with the new riverpod generator?

Answer (score 0):

`var users = ref.watch(usersProvider);` will have an `AsyncValue<User?>` as its value.  That's not a Stream.  A StreamProvider or a StreamNotifierProvider always produces an updating AsyncValue when watched or read or listened, *identical* to a FutureProvider or AsyncNotifierProvider.  The only difference between the two is the return value from `build()` (Stream vs Future). Beyond that, both of the async families work identically.

Comment: that's not true because I did this exact example in a previous project and users variable was a stream with the identical code